# Permissions not Refreshing

Tags: facebook-login, user-permissions

In summary, I'm setting up an app, and I have selected various User & Friend permissions (in particular, `user_likes` and `publish_actions`).  However, my app's authorization dialog fails to list these permissions, and instead indicates that my app is requesting access only to Basic Info.  Any ideas what might be wrong?

Here are some additional details:

- Previously, the authorization dialog was correctly showing the permissions I requested.  However, I was tinkering with a few different permission settings over the course of the morning, and now no matter what permissions I select, the authorization dialog lists only Basic Info.
- The authorization dialog preview (available in Settings|Permissions) does show that my app is requesting the permissions I've specified.  And yet, the actual authorization dialog does not
- The issue is not merely that the dialog does not displayi the permissions I've requested.  The app is only actually getting the Basic Info permissions.  (I know, because I receive an error indicating this when I try to do access likes in the app.)
- The issue is not just that the changes to the permissions take time to refresh and propagate on the Facebook servers.  I know because (a) I've waited several hours to no effect, and (b) other changes to my app's settings that affect the authorization dialog (such as the display name) are visible immediately
- The Default Account Privacy setting I choose does show up correctly on the authorization dialog, and changes to it are visible on the authorization dialog immediately.  Only the User & Friend permissions are not working.

And some additional background:

- The app itself is an iOS app being developed in Corona SDK.

Answer (score 1):

> and I have selected various User & Friend permissions

Where? In your app settings?

These settings affect only [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) – when a user clicks on a link to your app from within facebook.com.

When you are handling the login yourself, however, you have to specify the permissions at this point via the `scope` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The scope also worked for me after hours of headbanging.  Just be sure to use this notation: {scope: 'user_likes, user_location, etc'} at the end of the FB.login function to set all desired permissions from your app itself.